# Using Ruby Class method in form is possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class-method

I am now learning rails with the book, 'rails 4 application development'. I am following the chapter 2 now. The chapter introduces a tagging skill as follows.

**models/event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :organizers, class_name: "User"
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def all_tags=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

**views/events/_form.html.erb**

```
-- snipet
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :all_tags, "List All Tags, separate each tag with a comma" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :all_tags %>
</div>
-- snipet
```

Now when I try to create a new event record, I get this error as follows.

```
undefined method `all_tags' for #<Event:0x0000000aa36178>
```

As far as I understand, the method all_tags is defined for sure in the event model as a class method. I am now stuck at the part. You can see all the code in the following repository at github.

```
https://github.com/Kosmas/radh2
```

Comment: You've only shown `all_tags=` setter method.  You also need a getter for it. You could declare `attr_reader :all_tags` in `Event` model to do so.

Comment: It works well as I declared a getter as you advised. Why is a getter method   needed here?

Comment: Because both `f.label :all_tags` and `f.text_field :all_tags` are referencing it.